# Restful with java security

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I have to secure my restful web services so that if any one will get uri of my restful web services then also  with the help of that uri any one cant access my  restful web services . I want to design a restful web services in such a way that only my dynamic web application running in different server can access my restful web services .
I am doing this by setting authentication header , I am putting username of the user in authentication header and in restful web services i am checking these value from the data base , this is like session management , i am confuse whether this is good approach , because we should not mention session in restful web services .

second thing is that i am putting some encoded string in authentication header and we will also check these value in the filter of restful web services , for protecting from third party , is this approach is good , if not can you tell me the good approach ,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it save, use Server AND Client SSL-Certificates, each Client should hav its own Certificate that the Server checks. Your Restful-Server should have the ability to check client-certificates.

If you use Tomcat, here is a how-to:
http://www.chesterproductions.net.nz/blogs/it/code/configuring-client-certificate-authentication-with-tomcat-and-java/537/

Comment: Thanks , can you tell me that if my web application (say application A ) running on tomcat server can access my  restful web services running on glassfish with Server and client SSL certificate . This will protect my REST webservices from third party but can you tell me that if my application A is made for public but restful webservices is only for application A .  In this condition it will work ??. in short Application A is open for all uses but Restful weservices is access only by my application A .

Comment: If A is the Rest-Client and B (Glassfish) is the Rest-Server, you can secure only that connection. A can still be accessed without ssl, since only B will need Client-Certificats.